# counting occurrences between dates of different date intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have a query that give me a table like this:

```
 Person | Date_IN | Date_OUT | Structure
```

During a year a person ENTER and EXIT many times, ENTER and EXIT could be also the same day.

I'd like to count, for a specific day of year, how many person were IN each structure.

The final goal is to have, for a given period (1st march --> 31st march), the sum of total person for each day for each structure.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Are the `DATE_IN` and `DATE_OUT` columns actually dates, and contain no time component?  If I enter the building in the morning, then leave in the afternoon, then my friend enters the building after I leave in the afternoon, there was only ever a maximum of one person in the building at any one time; do you need to handle those cases?  This feels like you need to be a bit more rigorous around the process and requirements before trying to solve it in SQL, or at least express the problem space more rigorously.

Comment: Yes, DATE_IN e DATE_OUT is someting like 2018-03-07. I have only to count presence in that day. (people stay 1 or more days... something like an hotel)

Comment: Describe how you count _how many person were IN each structure_. If a person checked in on 1st March, checks out on 3rd March, was he _IN_ on 2nd March?

Comment: @keebOo . . . Please ask *another* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, what you mean by how many people are "in" the structure on a day.  Cover situations such as people being in the structure for more than one day and explain if there are any anomalies in the data, such as multiple ins for a person with no outs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following would work. It assumes that you have a table of dates (consists of one column which contains all the dates between 1950 and 2050) and you simply join it with the person check in/out table:

```
SELECT dates.date, Structure, COUNT(DISTINCT Person) Persons_on_That_Date
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN turndata ON dates.date BETWEEN Date_IN AND Date_OUT
WHERE dates.date BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-03-31'
GROUP BY dates.date, Structure
ORDER BY Structure, dates.date
```

[Demo Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aPzm8fvK1kem1jSGYnq1GL/0)

Note: the above assumes that the out date is inclusive (the person is counted as *inside* on that date). If out date is exclusive then the `ON` clause becomes:

```
... ON Date_IN <= dates.date AND dates.date < Date_OUT
```

Comment: No, it will. I mentioned using a table of dates.

Comment: If I were you, I'd wait for the OP to construct an example.

Comment: Added fiddle. See Room 2 example.

Comment: @SalmanA read and see the demo, seems correct, the next step is that the final solution I need is: I have **1 year "survey", 3 structures, about 600 person** and need to know for **each day of year**   .... some way to have a single query? Or I need to repeat the process for each day? (probably with a loop on a custom php page for example)

Comment: I've waited too long for an edit to the question or a proper response; not spending any more time on this except by adding this comment: `CROSS JOIN` the dates table with structures and `LEFT JOIN ... BETWEEN` with turndata table.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, data is grouped by structure for particular timeframe.

```
SELECT structure, COUNT(DISTINCT person) as no_of_person
FROM table_name
WHERE DATE(Date_IN) BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-31'
GROUP BY structure
```

Comment: What if the person entered on 07-28 and exited on 08-02?

Comment: @KeebOo has specified "I'd like to count, for a specific day of year, how many person were IN each structure."

Comment: @JERRY consider adding some text explaining your query.

Comment: @Strawberry ... if PERSON_1 enter day 1 and exit day 5 of month, and PERSON_2 enter day 3 and exit day 7:  day 1 = 1, day 2 = 1, day 3 = 2, day 4 = 2, day 5= 1, day 6 = 1, day 7 = 0

Answer (score 0):

You say there can be no multiple `date_in` for the same day and person, because a person is in at least one day. So for a given date we only must look at the latest event per person until then to see whether the person is/was in that day.

These are the steps:

- create a data set for the requiered days on-the-fly
- join with the table and get the last `date_in` until that day per person
- join with the table again to get the last records
- aggregate per day and count persons present

This is:

```
select
  data.day
  sum(t.date_in is not null and (t.date_out is null or t.date_out = data.day)) as count_in
from
(
  select days.day, t.person, max(t.date_in) as max_date_in
  from (select date '2018-03-01' as day union all ...) days
  left join t on t.date_in <= days.day
  group by days.day, t.person
) data
left join t on t.person = data.person and t.date_in = data.max_date_in
group by data.day
order by data.day;
```